# Prevent javascript function from changing style attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an unnamed javascript plug-in.

During a certain operation of said plugin, under a specific circumstance, the plugin changes the style attributes of certain elements on my page.

Without delving into the plugin code itself (I want to avoid that if possible), is there a way to prevent the style attributes of those elements from being altered? I'm thinking perhaps a block somehow, or a way to lock the current style attribute to prevent changes?

I'm leaving the plugin unnamed because, while it would be great if someone actually could walk me though editing a plugin's code to meet my needs, I strongly doubt that's going to happen. And if there is a solution that fits my above perimeters, it would be much more useful and easier to implement.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: have you tried just adding !important to those styles you dont want ever changed?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid simply diving into the source?

Comment: Why don't you want it to change the style attribute? What's it changing that you don't like?

Comment: @Oscar Godson - I don't want to prevent these styles from *ever* being changed; only sometimes, during a certain function. Plus, would that work? Even if we're talking about the style attribute of the tag, and not separate css?

Comment: @alpha123 - I'm too scared of the source code. I don't know javascript well enough to be able to feel confident in doing that. The plugin is Shadowbox.js btw.

Comment: @stefmikhail: Oh. Short of `!important`, I think changing the source is the only way to do what you want.

Comment: +1 for your comment for honesty :) (and that you mentioned which plugin it is ;))

Comment: @Chris Morgan - The plugin in question is Shadowbox.js, and I've worked very hard to come up with some alternate functionality in a certain circumstance. Basically, when the shadowbox closes, it changes the style of it's container to display:none, visibility:hidden, and opacity:0. Under this circumstance I want them all to be in their opened state.

Comment: @Felix Kling - Thanks bud. Honesty is always the way ;)

Comment: Thats easy enough, why not just ask how to prevent certain styles from happening in shadowbox? The code doesn't look too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add `!important` to the style rules that you wish to prevent the plugin from overriding (I'm assuming that it inserts inline styles.)

[Like this (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/UUqQ5/)

Comment: Actually, that might work. The only problem is that it will have to be added via javascript to the head of the page, at the beginning of my function, and removed at the end of it to allow for normal functioning of the plugin. Now all I have to remember is how to add style to the head using jQuery...

Comment: Or use the `!important` rule in a new selector and add/remove a class to the element (or element's container) with jQuery.

Comment: That might be a better idea actually. I used `.appendTo` to place the style in the head of the document. The problem is, when the function is complete, I want to remove the appended style. Not only do I not know how to do this, but I'm wondering if your new suggestion would be easier as I would only have to toggle a class? What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, toggling the class would be more straightforward as you can just use jQuery's `toggleClass()`.